# Why doesn't a Sequence get consumed when I assign it to an @var?

Tags: raku

According to the [class Seq docs](https://docs.raku.org/type/Seq):

> A Seq is born in a state where iterating it will consume the values.
> ...
> ...
> A Seq can also be constructed with the sequence operator `...`
> or one of its variants. Assigning the values of a Seq to an array
> consumes a Seq that is not lazy.

Extending the example in the docs:

```
use v6.d;

my $s = (1...5);
say $s;              # OUTPUT: «(1 2 3 4 5)␤» 
say $s.^name;        # OUTPUT: «Seq␤»

# My code:

say '-' x 10;

my @x = $s;
say @x;
say @x.^name;
say @x.elems;

say '-' x 10;

my @y = $s;
say @y;
say @y.^name;
say @y.elems;

--output:--
(1 2 3 4 5)
Seq
----------
[(1 2 3 4 5)]
Array
1
----------
[(1 2 3 4 5)]
Array
1
```

I expected the assignment:

```
my @x = $s;
```

to iterate over the Seq $s and consume $s during the assignment to @x.  And, I expected there to be 5 elements in @x.   But the output doesn't show that the Seq $s is being iterated over or consumed.

```
$s.is-lazy  #False
```

The docs seem warn you that a Seq will get iterated over when you might not expect it, and then the Seq will be consumed and the next attempt to iterate over the Seq will cause errors.  But, I seem to have the opposite problem: I can't make a Seq get consumed.

Answer (score 2):

*Only a partial answer (so far):*

It looks like all your assignments above into an `@array` go into the `[0]`th position of the array. Note how your `elems` above equals `1` one.

To assign each list element to each position of the array, you have to call `.list` on it (pretty sure `.List` and `.Array` will give you the same results), below:

```perl
my $t = (1...5);
my @z = $t.list;
say @z;
say @z.^name;
say @z.elems;
say "\nIterate:";
.say for @z;

#OUTPUT:

[1 2 3 4 5]
Array
5

Iterate:
1
2
3
4
5
```

---

*(Maybe the remainder of the answer, below):*

Why don't your assignments of `$s` above consume the `Seq`? Possibly because Raku thinks you've only *consumed* them as one element and have not *iterated* through the elements of `$s` individually.

Really, really, guessing here, but if after assigning `$t.list` to `@z` above, if I try to call `.say for $t` I get the following error:

```perl
#Add to previous `$t` code (at bottom):

.say for $t;

The iterator of this Seq is already in use/consumed by another Seq (you
might solve this by adding .cache on usages of the Seq, or by assigning
the Seq into an array)
  in block <unit> at - line 45
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You are evaluating the `Seq` in scalar context, therefor when you create the array, it views the `Seq` as a single element of the new array. You can coerce the `Seq` to an `Array` using `.Array`. Or, tell Raku that this should be evaluated in array-context, thus assigning the `Seq` to your new `Array` how you'd expect.

```
my $s = (1...5);
my @f = @($s);

say @f; # prints [1 2 3 4 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

@7stud - this is a fair question.

In raku, a basic idea is to use $ to denote scalar items and @ to denote multiple items. Consider this:

```
my $x = (1,2);
dd $x;    #Mu $x = $(1, 2) <-- a list inside a scalar container
```

```
my @y = $x;
dd @y;    #Mu @y = [(1, 2),] <--- array assignment does not auto-flatten
```

How about:

```
my @z = |$x;
dd @z;    #Mu @z = [1, 2]
```

The slip operator '|' is one way to force an iteration. Or call .List, .Array.

Comment: Except `$`-sigiled objects can be lists which can be iterated through with `for`, and `@`-sigiled objects can be 'singularified' with `given`. Does that make it clearer, or less clear?